# why I cannot use forward declaration when using template？

Tags: c++, templates

for non-template class, I can use forward declaration in the header file. But it gave me error when I use it in the template class.

I have to include the header file, I would like to know the reason.

```
class Pu;

template <typename T>
class Pt()
{
     void test(Pu<T> u);
}
```

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: I believe you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: This syntax for forward declaration works: `template <typename T> class MyClass;` - did you intend to use anything else?

Comment: @Anatolyg, please move this to the answer, you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works just fine, if you do it properly!

Remember, `Pu` is a *class template*, not a class, so it must be declared as such:

```
template <typename T>      // N.B. this line
class Pu;

template <typename T>
class Pt                   // N.B. no "()"
{
     void test(Pu<T> u);
};                         // N.B. ";"
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/463a87d44c97f4f4))